# UWP - change background color of button

Tags: c#, button, background, styles, win-universal-app

I want to change default background of button in all conditions. But when I'm using

```
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```

I'm getting a red button and gray button if button pressed.
I thinking that I must change a style of button. But how I can set a color in style?

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this animation:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You can see that it sets Background property for RootGrid to `{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}` value when pressed. Simply replace it with your color and you good to go:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```